# Does PersonalizedPageRank class in JUNG library have bug?

Tags: jung, pagerank, jung2

I am using JUNG library for its "PageRankWithPriors class". I used a very small graph (with just 3 nodes) to test this class. when there isn't any node with self-edge the output is OK,  but if the graph contains a node with a self-edge the output becomes incorrect (the final rank of nodes is not in the form of probability value and their sum is not equal to 1). the output is :

0.2997601918465228

0.1247002398081535

0.1918465227817746

i used "setHyperedgesAreSelfLoops(true)" but the outputs are still incorrect:

320751.99531359226

609574.2619040733

2554381.251484884

why "PersonalizedPageRank class" does  not work correctly? Is there a bug inside of it or i do something wrong?

my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{           
   weigth[0][1]=0.2;
   weigth[0][2]=0.8;
   weigth[1][0]=1;
   weigth[2][1]= 0.5;
   weigth[2][2]= 0.5;       

   prior[0]=1;
   prior[1]=0;
   prior[2]=0;

   Graph<Integer, String> g = new DirectedSparseGraph<Integer, String> ();

   g.addVertex(new Integer(0));
   g.addVertex(new Integer(1));
   g.addVertex(new Integer(2));

   g.addEdge("0->1", 0, 1, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
   g.addEdge("0->2", 0, 2, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
   g.addEdge("1->0", 1, 0, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
   g.addEdge("2->1", 2, 1, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
   g.addEdge("2->2", 2, 2, EdgeType.DIRECTED);


   Transformer<String, Double> edge_weigths = 
           new Transformer<String, Double>()
           {
        @Override
                public Double transform(String e) 
                {
                    String[] split = e.split("->");           
                    return weigth[Integer.parseInt(split[0])][Integer.parseInt(split[1])];
                }           
           };

   Transformer<Integer, Double> vertex_prior = 
           new Transformer<Integer, Double>()
           {            
        @Override
                public Double transform(Integer v) 
                {                        
                    return prior[v];            
                }           
           }


   PageRankWithPriors prp = new PageRankWithPriors(g, edge_weigths, vertex_prior, 0.2);        
   prp.setHyperedgesAreSelfLoops(true);   
   prp.evaluate();

   System.out.println(prp.getVertexScore(0));
   System.out.println(prp.getVertexScore(1));
   System.out.println(prp.getVertexScore(2));   


}
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I'm not sure why you're calling `setHyperEdgesAreSelfLoops()`, since you're not working with a hypergraph.  Digging in a bit, it looks like the resultant numbers are weird because we're not guarding against the possibility that the graph is not a hypergraph when that method is called.  Oops.  In the meantime, don't call that if your graph isn't a Hypergraph.  :)

(2) I think that this may be the problem:

`g.addVertex((Integer)0);`

I believe that casting 0 (or any other integer) to Integer is not the same thing as `new Integer(0)` or `Integer.valueOf(0)`.  What you're doing is actually casting the number 0 to a Integer reference.  So I'll bet that if you ask your graph how many vertices it has, it will report '6' rather than '3'.

The good news is that `addEdge()` will automatically add the vertex arguments to the graph as needed, so you can just remove the `addVertex()` calls entirely.

Comment: i tested your suggestion but "((Integer)0)" is not the problem!

Comment: What did you change and what was the effect?

Comment: 1)without changing anything the number of vertices is 3 not 6.        2)i changed "(Integer)0" to "new Integer(0)" but the results were as the same as before.

Comment: Interesting.  Ah, I think I may have spotted the problem.  Try removing the self-loop and making it a different edge.  I think the code has a bug for self-loops.  (Ironically enough.)